# AWS EC2 instance is hanging up everytime I upload a new file for around 5-15 seconds with ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a basic AWS EC2 instance with my domain mapped and all is working fine, the only issue is unconsistent uptime while i'm working.

I've connected my PHPStorm IDE to upload new files (or amend existing ones), every time I upload/amend a file, my website goes down with `ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED` for around 5-15 seconds and then returns to normal.

As a developer this impedes my productivity.
I have no idea how to resolve this issue, has anyone came across this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the resource usage like cpu/disk ?

Comment: You’ve not provided any details of your app, but considering the error and that the site is unavailable for such a short period of time and recovers itself, I’d start by checking if that 5-15 seconds of downtime is the server rebuilding or reindexing or rebooting or something like that as a result of the code changes.